# библиотеки отдельно в подпапке папке от главной папки с exe файлом

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Использую упаковщик `pyinstaller` с опцией `onedir`, что использовать после на других PC.
Все ок, но когда все нужные библиотеки в перемешку с "*.exe" файлом, то выглядит это не очень. Я поискал в интернете решение чтобы получить рабочую структуру:

```
-main:
  -subfolder:
    -other libs (example dll)
  -*.exe
```

Но пару вариантов оказались не рабочие для новых версий pyinstaller. Один из вариантов:

```
import sys
import os
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    dir = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(dir, 'Lib'))
```

Этот мини скрипт я вызывал при компиляции через: `--runtime-hook option.py`
Он рабочий, но не полностью, так как есть библиотеки, например: `tkinter`, `pillow`, `torch` и другие (а их оказалось у меня больше половины), которые не хотят работать в другой директории, кроме главной. Читал, что можно как-то указать просто место поиска нужных библиотек, но я что-то не понял как это сделать и чтобы конфликта небыло при запуске приложения. Решение нужно кроссплатформенное, для windows или linux os.